# QJsonDocument::array() and QJsonDocument::object()

Tags: qt, qjson

I am reading the [QJsonDocument documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#details) and I use `QJsonDocument` with following line:

```
emit this->ueSignalNewDataArrivedPlaces(QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData(incomingData[0].toByteArray()));
```

and I do not understand, after this line, should I use  [QJsonDocument::array()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#array) or [QJsonDocument::object()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#object), i.e., in what situations does `QJsonDocument` create `array` and in what situations does create `object`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JSON array is an ordered list, it is written as:

```
[ <item1>, <item2>, <item3> ]
```

while a JSON object is a named list, written as:

```
{
    <name1>: <item1>,
    <name2>: <item2>
}
```

In Qt, a `QJsonArray` is equivalent to a `QVariantList` (`QList<QVariant>`) and a `QJsonObject` is equivalent to `QVariantMap` (`QMap<QString, QVariant>`).

Which one you have to use depends on the file you are parsing.
For instance, taking Wikipedia example:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "isAlive": true,
  "age": 25,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    },
    {
      "type": "mobile",
      "number": "123 456-7890"
    }
  ],
  "children": [],
  "spouse": null
}
```

You would use a `QJsonArray` to get the list of `phoneNumbers`, each element of `phoneNumbers` is a `QJsonObject` whith 2 named values: `type` and `number`.

If in your code you need to manipulate a JSON element but you do not know its type you can use `QJsonValue`, which is one of: `QJsonObject`, `QJsonArray`, `bool`, `double` or a `QString`

Comment: hmm, that's it! I thought `QJsonObject` is created instead of `QJsonArray` if `json` data source containts only "one record".

Comment: And can I be sure for "invalid" `json` format if both `isObject()` and `isArray()` return `true`?

Comment: @Kernelpanic You can't have both returning true. Your root element can't be both an array and an object.

If you want the proof, in Qt sources `QJsonDocument::isArray()` calls `QJsonPrivate::Base::isArray()`, which is implemented as inline `bool isArray() const { return !isObject(); }`. Also you can check for invalid JSON with `QJsonDocument::isNull()` and with the second parameter of `QJsonDocument::fromJson()`.